# bitwise NOT of signed and unsigned integers in C

Tags: c, gcc, signed

I was debugging an issue and figured out that the following snippet(sanitized) was the reason for the issue.

```
uint64_t testflag = 0;
testflag &= ~(0x08ul); //bug 
testflag &= ~(0x08l);  //expected
```

I compared the generated assembly and see this

```
  uint64_t testflag = 0;
804851e:    c7 45 d8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x28(%ebp)
8048525:    c7 45 dc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x24(%ebp)
  testflag &= ~(0x08ul);
804852c:    83 65 d8 f7             andl   $0xfffffff7,-0x28(%ebp)
8048530:    83 65 dc 00             andl   $0x0,-0x24(%ebp)
  testflag &= ~(0x08l);
8048534:    83 65 d8 f7             andl   $0xfffffff7,-0x28(%ebp)
8048538:    83 65 dc ff             andl   $0xffffffff,-0x24(%ebp)
```

Why does the `NOT operator` of `unsigned long` cause the compiler to AND `0` with the higher bytes instead of `ffffffff`.

My gcc version is `gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 (Red Hat 4.9.2)` on a 64bit machine.

Comment: What is `sizeof(unsigned long)`?

Comment: sign-extension vs zero-extension, since long is 32 bits on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 32-bit `unsigned long/long`...

```
uint64_t testflag;
```

---

```
 0x08ul     --> 00 00 00 08
 ~(0x08ul)  --> FF FF FF F7
some_uint32_t = FF FF FF F7 

testflag &= some_uint32_t;
testflag = testflag & some_uint32_t
testflag = testflag & (uint64_t) some_uint32_t
testflag = testflag & (uint64_t) FF FF FF F7  (or 4,294,967,288)
testflag = testflag & 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF F7
```

Converting a 32-bit unsigned to `uint64_t` is a simply 0 extend.

---

Now with `~(0x08l)`

```
 0x08l      --> 00 00 00 08
 ~(0x08l)   --> FF FF FF F7
some_int32_t  = FF FF FF F7 

testflag &= some_int32_t;
testflag = testflag & some_int32_t
testflag = testflag & (uint64_t) some_int32_t
testflag = testflag & (uint64_t)  FF FF FF F7 (or - 8)
testflag = testflag & FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F7 (or 18,446,744,073,709,551,608)
```

-8 as a `uint64_t` is very nearly the maximum value for `uint64_t`.
With 2's complement, the result is the sign bit of OP's `long` is extended. [@Marc Glisse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081861/bitwise-not-of-signed-and-unsigned-integers-in-c/43082084#comment73247014_43081861)